# How do I scrape Google Search results (on a big scale kinda)?

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, google-search

From what I've heard, google doesn't like being crawled/scraped. Found a similar question month ago on stackoverflow when I was about to start this project (Can't find it now.). Someone said that using proxy is a way to go, so I got proxymesh. And I'm guessing that I need to send requests at a "random rate" to have human like behavior. Like if I spam requests every 0.1 seconds I'll probably get blocked. I also read that I need to use a browser, or something that activates javascript, again in order to mimic human like behavior. And to scrape lots of results quickly, I thought to run multiple bots simultaneously but I don't know how to do that yet (Started learning recently).

**So my question is:** How do I do that?

The parts that are not so clear for me:

**1.** Browser for scraping? Do I need it? Is it efficient?(Previously I just used bs4 and requests)

**2.** Will timer make a difference? Or is google sophisticated enough to notice that too?

**3.** Running mutiple bots. I get 100 or 220 IP adresses a day (with limited data I think) from proxy and I thought if I run multiple bots and assign each one with a unique IP adress I will be able to scrape results fast? But I have no idea how to run multiple bots and stuff...

How I planned to use the bot (So that you have a better understanding of what I mean I guess):

Use case 1:

1. Search for a specific website.
2. Open that website and get data that I need.
3. Repeat. (I have lots of websites that i need to search, lets say a million)

Use case 2:

1. Search for a broad keyword.
2. Open about first 50-100 websites in search result and get data that I need.
3. Repeat.

I want to do both of those.

Comment: Why not just sign up for the developer API?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Well, searching this many results will cost a LOT of money. And I'm not that rich :P

Comment: Or I'm a missing something?

Comment: How many is "this many"? How big of a scale is "a big scale, kinda"? Put numbers - and rationale - on it. What *problem are you trying to solve* by doing these searches? Are you trying to offer a service to others, or satisfy your own quest for knowledge, or something else?

Comment: I wrote "Lets say a million" its work related but mostly to "satisfy my own quest for knowledge"

Comment: It is against Google's [Webmaster Guidelines](//developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/webmaster-guidelines) and [terms of service](//policies.google.com/terms/archive/20020906?hl=en) to submit programmatic search queries. Running this code against Google is likely to cause Google to show captcha for searches from your IP address.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) with [puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer) and running this code as a starting point. It will get you the links for a given google search. Using different IP addresses is good, but also try turning off your location services, clearing your cache constantly, and clearing anything else google might use to uniquely identify you. Splitting across multiple IP addresses will save you time, but then you're paying with processing power, so there's always a cost. Good luck.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

function googleBot(search, pageIndex) {
    puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        defaultViewport: null,
        args: ['--start-fullscreen'],
        timeout: 1000 * 30
    }).then(async browser => {
        try{
            const pages = await browser.pages();
            const page = pages[0];

            //close on page errors
            page.on("error", async function(error){
                console.log("FORCED CLOSE DUE TO ERROR: " + error);
                await browser.close();
            });
            
            //dismiss any alerts
            page.on('dialog', async dialog => {
                await dialog.dismiss();
            });
            
            var links = await runOnURLAndReturn("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + search + "&start=" + pageIndex * 10, ".LC20lb", async () => {
                try{
                    return await new Promise(resolve => {
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            var links = [];
                            
                            var searchResults = document.querySelectorAll(".LC20lb");
                            for(var i = 0; i < searchResults.length; i++){
                                if(searchResults[i].parentNode.tagName == "A"){
                                    links[links.length] = searchResults[i].parentNode.href;
                                }
                            }
                            
                            resolve(links);
                        }, 3000 + (Math.random() * 3000));
                    }, function(){
                        throw "link scraping promise error";
                    });
                }
                catch(error){
                    return false;
                }
            });
            
            console.log(links.join("\n"));
            
            await browser.close();

            async function runOnURLAndReturn(url, loadedSelector, fn) {
                try{
                    await page.goto(url, {timeout: 1000 * 30});
                    await page.waitFor(loadedSelector, {timeout: 1000 * 30});
                    return await page.evaluate(fn);
                }
                catch(error){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(error){
            console.log("FORCED CLOSE DUE TO ERROR: " + error);
            await browser.close();
        }
    }, async reason => {});
}
googleBot("something", 0);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm currently learning python but thanks for the tips and code.

Answer (score 2):

> Browser for scraping?

It depends. If something highly dynamic needs to be done then yes. For Google search, it's not necessary. In some cases, you need to impersonate your TSL, HTTP handshake to pretend that you're a browser. For that case, you can use [`curl-impersonate`](https://github.com/lwthiker/curl-impersonate) or [`selenium-stealth`](https://github.com/diprajpatra/selenium-stealth) which can bypass most CAPTCHAs.

> Running mutiple bots.

Residential proxies are the ideal choice. And the ideal scenario is to use them in combination with a CAPTCHA solver such as [2captcha](https://2captcha.com/). An additional method could be to [rotate user-agents](https://serpapi.com/blog/how-to-reduce-chance-of-being-blocked-while-web/#rotate-user-agents) in combination with rotating proxies in combo with CAPTCHA solver.

Sometimes there's no need to rotate user-agents if an [additional request headers](https://serpapi.com/blog/how-to-reduce-chance-of-being-blocked-while-web/#add_headers) needs to be passed while making a request.

There's a [reducing the chance of being blocked while web scraping](https://serpapi.com/blog/how-to-reduce-chance-of-being-blocked-while-web/) blog post if you need a little bit more info.

---

If you don't want to use any APIs, have a look at my recent Stackoverflow answer where I showed [how to parse Google Search data from all pages using pagination using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74305096/15164646) [`bs4`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

However, most likely the most reliable solution to your problem is some third-party API that removes the need on your part for continuous parser maintenance (CSS selectors change, etc).

There's a [Google Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/search-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan. The advantage is that it will bypass blocking (including CAPTCHA) from Google and other search engines, and there's no need to create a parser from scratch and maintain it.

Below is an asynchronous example that makes several requests at once and returns JSON data. In this example, I've shown only 4 requests. Have a look at [time comparisons of 500 requests](https://serpapi.com/blog/making-async-requests-with-serpapi/) (not multithreaded):

| Sync | Async |
| --- | --- |
| 13m 43.311s | 5m 3.663s |

Code and example in the [online IDE](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/scrape-google-search-results-using-async-requests-serpapi#main.py):

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
from queue import Queue
import os, re, json

queries = [
    'burly',        # this is an example, 
    'silk',         # the number of search queries can be much more.
    'monkey',
    'abortive',
    'hot'
]

search_queue = Queue()

for query in queries:
    params = {
        'api_key': os.getenv('API_KEY'),  # serpapi api key
        'engine': 'google',               # search engine
        'device': 'desktop',              # device type
        'q': query,                       # search query
        'async': True                     # async batch requests
    }

    search = GoogleSearch(params)        # where data extraction happens
    results = search.get_dict()          # JSON -> Python dict
    
    if 'error' in results:
        print(results['error'])
        break

    print(f"add search to the queue with ID: {results['search_metadata']}")
    search_queue.put(results)
    
data = []

while not search_queue.empty():
    result = search_queue.get()
    search_id = result['search_metadata']['id']

    print(f'Get search from archive: {search_id}')
    search_archived = search.get_search_archive(search_id)
    
    print(f"Search ID: {search_id}, Status: {search_archived['search_metadata']['status']}")

    if re.search(r'Cached|Success', search_archived['search_metadata']['status']): # processing, success, error 
        for result in search_archived.get('organic_results', []):
            data.append({
                'title': result.get('title'),
                'link': result.get('link'),
                'displayed_link': result.get('displayed_link'),
                'snippet': result.get('snippet')
            })
    else:
        print(f'Requeue search: {search_id}')
        search_queue.put(result)
        
print(json.dumps(data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
print('all searches completed')
```

Example output:

```json
[
  {
    "title": "Burly Definition & Meaning - Merriam-Webster",
    "link": "https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/burly",
    "displayed_link": "https://www.merriam-webster.com › dictionary › burly",
    "snippet": "The meaning of BURLY is strongly and heavily built : husky. How to use burly in a sentence."
  },
  {
    "title": "Burly Definition & Meaning - Dictionary.com",
    "link": "https://www.dictionary.com/browse/burly",
    "displayed_link": "https://www.dictionary.com › browse › burly",
    "snippet": "adjective, bur·li·er, bur·li·est. large in bodily size; stout; sturdy."
  },
  {
    "title": "BURLY Brewing Company | Castle Rock Brewery | Castle ...",
    "link": "http://www.burlybrewing.com/",
    "displayed_link": "http://www.burlybrewing.com",
    "snippet": "Welcome to BURLY Brewing, where craft beer is our specialty. Check out our live events, rotating food trucks, and fun for everyone."
  },
  {
    "title": "Burly - Definition, Meaning & Synonyms - Vocabulary.com",
    "link": "https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/burly",
    "displayed_link": "https://www.vocabulary.com › dictionary › burly",
    "snippet": "The adjective burly describes someone (usually male) who is muscular and beefy. Types of people that you might describe as burly?"
  },
  # ...
]
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to scrape Google search results on a large scale, it may be worth going with off-the-shelf solutions like [Octoparse](https://www.octoparse.com/) or [Bright Data](https://get.brightdata.com/bd7914). The latter, for example, incorporates a SERP API to fetch search engine results data and also offers rotating proxies, etc. to bypass Captcha solving/website blocks.